# Saving data on OneDrive or Google Drive (Heroku)

Tags: python, django, heroku, storage, onedrive

Hello I am new to using django and heroku and through out me designing my first project I Found out that I need a AWS 3 account/S3 storage to store images/files but I was wondering if I could use either a OneDrive or a Google Drive to save the files/images that the user uploads and if so, is it Like when using a AWS 3 storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku has an “ephemeral” hard drive, this means that you can write files to disk, but those files will not persist after the application is restarted.
You would get them lost in case you restart your dyno or deploy a new release ([Active Storage on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/active-storage-on-heroku).

But you have a few options to get your data stored although that is the case.

1. Use one of Herokus services to do so and pay for it ([Databases & Data Management](https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/data-management)
2. Use one of the third party providers which offer their services at Herokus marketplace and pay for it ([Heroku Add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons)
3. Use one of your personal preferred other providers which offers such kind of data storage service (e.g. one of those: [HDrive](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/hdrive).

Which options would fit your plan depends a bit on your application and the kind of data you want to store.
You are using a sqlite-db and need an additional file storage and all together needs to be migrated to Heroku: [Migrating your Django Project to Heroku](https://realpython.com/migrating-your-django-project-to-heroku/#data-transfer)

Comment: Lets say I only want to store users images and display them to the user or another example I want to display a homepage image of my choice  and displaying them on my page using HDrive ?

Comment: Good question. Are the src-pathes to those images hardcoded in your source code or dynamically generated out of a database?

Comment: This is important to know to be able to decide whether you only need an external filestorage or an additional database too.

Comment: I made an upload in views.py where the user image get save with an ID of the user and stored in a media file on my local device.

Comment: in my html file the image get call ed like this ```  {% if topic.image %}
                                <image src="{{topic.image.url}}" style="width:200px">
                            {% else %}    ```

Comment: That means: you're using a database (which one?) and you definitely need a datastorage.

Comment: I am using  sqlite3 and what would you recommend to use right here