# Does Heroku save my list changes forever or do they disappear?

Tags: java, list, spring-boot, heroku

I'm doing a Heroku project, which where I have a list of players (you can delete, modify or add them on site). However, when I push changes to my code to GitHub, the players I have added outside of the code disappear. Is this normal, and how do I work around this?

My Heroku:

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has an “ephemeral” hard drive, this means that you can write files to disk, but those files will not persist after the application is restarted. And this is the case if you deploy your code from GitHub into your Heroku bucket.

Your questions should be answered in there: [Saving data on OneDrive or Google Drive (Heroku)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824365/saving-data-on-onedrive-or-google-drive-heroku)